# Creating csv results in crash

Tags: java, android

So Im trying to make my android app create a CSV file but it doesnt seem to work and crashes. I've tested the rest of my code and it's working fine but this seems too cause a crash :/ A csv file is create thou on the root of my phone that's empty

updated my logcat
my code :

```
FileWriter writefile;
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File MesurementFile= new File(root, "Data.csv");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
String date = "Current date";
String a= "a size : ";
String b="b Size : ";

public void writeCsvHeader() throws IOException {
    String line = String.format("%s,%s,%s\n",date,a,b);
    writer = new FileWriter(csvfile);
    writer.write(line);
}

public void writeCsvData(long a, long b)throws IOException {
    String line = String.format("%f,%f,%f,%f\n", formattedDate ,a,b);
    writer.write(line);
    try {

        writer = new FileWriter(MesurementFile);
        writeCsvData(a,b);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Stacktrace :

```
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482): Process: com.extras, PID: 9482
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.extras.MyService@41e9c500 with Intent { cmp=com.extras/.MyService (has extras) }: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %f can't format java.lang.String arguments
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2737)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:144)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5140)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482): Caused by: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %f can't format java.lang.String arguments
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at java.util.Formatter.badArgumentType(Formatter.java:1489)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at java.util.Formatter.transformFromFloat(Formatter.java:2038)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at java.util.Formatter.transform(Formatter.java:1465)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1081)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1042)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1011)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1999)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1973)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:83)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at com.extras.MyService.onStartCommand(MyService.java:46)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2720)
07-25 14:07:54.874: E/AndroidRuntime(9482):     ... 10 more





 07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219): Process: com.extras, PID: 13219
    07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219): java.lang.StackOverflowError
    07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at     java.lang.Thread.currentThread(Thread.java:470)
    07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:53)
    07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at java.util.Formatter.getDecimalFormat(Formatter.java:594)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at     java.util.Formatter.transformF(Formatter.java:2215)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at java.util.Formatter.transformFromFloat(Formatter.java:2055)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at java.util.Formatter.transform(Formatter.java:1465)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1081)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1042)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1011)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1999)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1973)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:83)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writeCsvData(MyService.java:88)
07-25 14:24:25.994: E/AndroidRuntime(13219):    at com.extras.MyService.writ
```

Comment: Please, include the stack trace. Anyway, consider using a CSV library to write out CSVs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: I've considered using opencsv or supercsv but I rather try making my own file from scratch code

Answer (score 0):

You are using %f for formatting String and hence it is complaining. Also there are four %f and you are passing 3 values (formattedDate, a, b)

```
String line = String.format("%f,%f,%f,%f\n", formattedDate ,a,b);
```

Answer (score 0):

> %f can't format java.lang.String arguments

that basically says everything you need. You try to write a String but your placeholder only accepts `%f` which is `float` (if I recall correctly).

So just check what type of arguments you have here and change the `%f` to `%s` or change the type of argument.

```
// at least one %f is wrong here...
String line = String.format("%f,%f,%f,%f\n", formattedDate ,a,b);
```

Update:

You are now seeing a `StackOverflowException` because you call your own method within the same method. That is an infinite loop and normally called "recursion". Recursion need to have some well defined and bulletproof ending condition. The stack size is the limit of the loops the recursion can do, you are exceeding that limit.

```
public void writeCsvData(long a, long b)throws IOException {
    String line = String.format("%f,%f,%f,%f\n", formattedDate ,a,b);
    writer.write(line);
    try {

        writer = new FileWriter(MesurementFile);
        writeCsvData(a,b); // THIS cause the loop

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You need to find a way to write just one line and repeatedly call that within a loop. To find out how to do that is up to you :)

Comment: Changing it to ("%s,%f,%f) didnt help :/ stil the same problem ,  updated my stack

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: `java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %f` can't format `java.lang.String` arguments

```
String line = String.format("%f,%f,%f,%f\n", formattedDate ,a,b);
```

I see three problems here:

1. You are using `%f`(floating point formatting) while passing `long` values (no floating point )
2. Your format requires four parameters, you are passing only three parameters.
3. `formattedDate` is a `String`, which is not formattable with `%f`, which is for floating point numbers.